# How to change the server side of these lines of codes to make it work?

Tags: r, data-analysis

I'm just a beginner user of R so it might be a very easy problem.

So I have this code. The question is that what should I write on the server-side to make it work? Because in my version I can choose a different continent with the third `selectInput` function but it does not have any effect on the barplot and also freezes my computer. Thank you for your help in advance!

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Bar Chart"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      widht=2,
      selectInput("xaxis","Select the value for X Axis",colnames(data2),selected = "countriesAndTerritorities"),
      selectInput("yaxis","Select the value for Y Axis",colnames(data2),selected = "cases"),
      selectInput("filter","Selec filter",choices = data2$continentExp)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("bar"),
      width = 20
    )
  )
))
shinyServer(function(input,output){
  data2 %>% filter(continens==data2$continentExp)
  output$bar <- renderPlot({
    bar2 <- tapply(data2[,input$yaxis],list(data2[,input$xaxis]),sum)
    barplot(bar2,beside=input$sidebar,las=2)
  })
})
```

This line of code maybe usless but i didn't know how to change the server side.

```
data2 %>% filter(continens==data2$continentExp)
```

data:

```
structure(list(dateRep = c("01/12/2020", "30/11/2020", "29/11/2020", 
"28/11/2020", "27/11/2020", "26/11/2020", "25/11/2020", "24/11/2020", 
"23/11/2020", "22/11/2020", "21/11/2020", "20/11/2020", "19/11/2020", 
"18/11/2020", "17/11/2020", "16/11/2020", "15/11/2020", "14/11/2020", 
"13/11/2020", "12/11/2020"), day = c(1L, 30L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 
26L, 25L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 
13L, 12L), month = c(12L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), 
    year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), cases = c(272L, 0L, 228L, 214L, 
    0L, 200L, 185L, 246L, 252L, 154L, 232L, 282L, 0L, 383L, 65L, 
    163L, 205L, 66L, 360L, 146L), deaths = c(11L, 0L, 11L, 15L, 
    0L, 12L, 13L, 17L, 8L, 12L, 25L, 5L, 0L, 13L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 
    10L, 14L, 4L), countriesAndTerritories = c("Afghanistan", 
    "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
    "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
    "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
    "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
    "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), geoId = c("AF", 
    "AF", "AF", "AF", "AF", "AF", "AF", "AF", "AF", "AF", "AF", 
    "AF", "AF", "AF", "AF", "AF", "AF", "AF", "AF", "AF"), countryterritoryCode = c("AFG", 
    "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", 
    "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", 
    "AFG"), popData2019 = c(38041757L, 38041757L, 38041757L, 
    38041757L, 38041757L, 38041757L, 38041757L, 38041757L, 38041757L, 
    38041757L, 38041757L, 38041757L, 38041757L, 38041757L, 38041757L, 
    38041757L, 38041757L, 38041757L, 38041757L, 38041757L), continentExp = c("Asia", 
    "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
    "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
    "Asia", "Asia", "Asia"), Cumulative_number_for_14_days_of_COVID.19_cases_per_100000 = c(6.96077208, 
    6.41663317, 6.8451097, 6.78464983, 6.39560365, 7.34193218, 
    7.1999829, 6.71367519, 6.655844, 6.20370926, 6.13010593, 
    5.6727138, 5.03657073, 5.35464227, 4.57392123, 4.65278194, 
    4.57129254, 4.23219148, 4.47140231, 3.84840269)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I thinnk in your `filter` you need `== input$filter`.  Can you show few rows of `data2` with `dput` so that it can be tested.  Also, there is no input for 'sidebar' in the `UI` and some of the values have typos `widht`should be `width`

Comment: I just added a picture of my data in the description

Comment: The issue with image is that we cannot copy that data for testing.  Can you use `dput(head(yourdata, 20))`

Comment: `data2 %>% filter(...)` is an unused call: not only is it in the wrong place for a shiny server (it should be within a reactive component, right?), but you also don't capture its output/results.

Comment: i think i added the required data.